# Does $\int_0^{\infty} \left( p + q W \left( r e^{- s x + t} \right) + u x \right) e^{- x} d x$ have a closed-form expression?

Tags: integration, closed-form, lambert-w

Does $\int_0^{\infty} \left( p + q W \left( r e^{- s x + t} \right) + u x \right)
e^{- x} d x$ (with 6 variables) where W is the Lambert W function (also known as ProductLog in Mathematica) have a closed-form expression? If we drop the variable $s$ from the expression Maple is able calculate 
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \left( p + q W \left( r e^{- x + t} \right) + u x \right)
e^{- x} d x = q W \left( r e^t \right) + \frac{q}{W \left( r e^t \right)}
- q + u + p - \frac{q}{r e^t}
$$ 
which agrees with numerical calculations, so my gut feeling is that such an expression should exist for the 6-variable expression as well, but Maple nor Mathematica are able to compute it.

To simplify the problem a bit let's consider a simpler integral, $$\int_0^{\infty} W \left( e^{- s x} \right) e^{- x} d x$$
If $s=1$ then we have $$\begin{array}{ll}
  \int_0^{\infty} W \left( e^{- x} \right) e^{- x} d x & = \frac{1 - 2 W
  \left( 1 \right) + W \left( 1 \right)^2}{W \left( 1 \right)}\\
  & = 0.330366124761680583225170439162
\end{array}$$ which is the solution to $$\left\{ y : y - \frac{1}{W \left( 1 \right)} = W \left( 1 \right) - 2
\right\}$$

If $s=1/2$ then Maple is not able to immediately find  an answer but it is seen to be true numerically that we have(thanks to the amazing and wonderful [RIES program](http://mrob.com/pub/ries/src/ries.c.txt)) $$\begin{array}{ll}
  \int_0^{\infty} W \left( e^{- \frac{x}{2}} \right) e^{- x} d x & =
  \frac{- 1 + 2 W \left( 1 \right) - W \left( 1 \right)^2 + 4 W \left( 1
  \right)^3}{4 W \left( 1 \right)^2}\\
  & = 0.421516016690748181742333199330
\end{array}$$ which is the solution to $$\left\{ y : \cos \left( \pi \sqrt{W \left( 1 \right) - y} \right) = \sin
\left( \frac{\pi}{2 W \left( 1 \right)} \right) \right\}$$

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $e^te^{-t} = 1$?

Comment: Of course! I've edited the expression, a bit simpler now, it's silly that I didn't see that at first but Maple only got rid of it with the collect and expand commands, not simplify.

Comment: Scroll down this [poster](http://www.orcca.on.ca/LambertW/). There is something related.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\infty} W \left( e^{- s x} \right) e^{- x} d x = W(1)+\left(-\frac{1}{s}\right)^{-\frac{1}{s}}\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)-s\;\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{s},-\frac{W(1)}{s}\right)\right),$$

where $\Gamma(z)$ is the [Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) and $\Gamma(a,z)$ is the [incomplete Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html).

To calculate this, change variable $y=e^{-x}$, then transpose the function graph to replace $W(y)$ with its inverse function $e^z z$.

Comment: Very nice formula! Mathematica is not able to calculate this.